# Android Proguard and Android frameworks: is there a conflict?

Tags: android, proguard

For the moment I am developing small Android projects to practice with the Android prorgramming. However, once on the market, I would like to obfuscate / optimise the APK thanks to ProGuard. But this tool renames classes to obfuscate the code, so:

1. Is it safe to use tools like Android Query to write the code?
2. If it is not safe, what are some framework examples that can be used safely with Pro Guard?
3. What could be a solution to the problem? Or should I write everything using the good old Android style and forget about a "write less, do more" approach?
4. How do I identify the tools that are ProGuard-safe from the ones that are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use third party libraries (jar files). You could use a 3 step approach:

1. If the third party jar explicitly supports Android, it will have a proguard configuration. Usually this is a snippet that you merge into your proguard-project.txt.
2. If there is no such explicit support, you may still try to use the jar, obfuscate and test your app. If errors occur, gradually exclude classes from obfuscation until it works. A common problem is that libraries use reflection to instantiate classes and call methods which breaks after obfuscation.
3. Exclude the whole library from obfuscation. This will work in any case and proguard will not touch the library at all. (The Android toolchain will still repackage the contents of the jar into your apk which might cause problems.) This will also produce the least obfuscated result and should really be your last resort.

In any case, obfuscation is not a switch that you simply toggle. You'll need to get familiar with proguard config files which involves a learning curve.

Comment: What about using tools such as AndroidQuery or Roboguice/AndroidAnnotations?
The first one deals with elements through string names, the second ones instead generate subclasses.
I suppose the second ones are more resilient to ProGuard obfuscation than the first one, but I'd like more insights.

Comment: Annotations are usually fine but reflection will most probably cause issues. Just imagine that every class, method and field will have a different name after obfuscation. If your library makes any assumptions about the names it will not work.

Comment: Here's a suggestion for an AndroidQuery proguard configuration: http://blog.androidquery.com/2011/06/android-optimization-with-proper.html. IMHO they are taking a very wide approach (which probably makes obfuscation useless), I would take the time and only exclude the classes and methods that really break. Proguard knows many ways to make things easier for you, e.g. you can keep all classes that have a common superclass or implement a specific interface.